# What is the best way to free browser memory when working with large arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is how I have things setup:

- container.html
- database1.js (contains large array called **database1**)
- database2.js (contains large array called **database2**)

Here's a sample of the array (shortened from 6000+ rows to 2):

```
var database1=[[
    "2010-01-03 07:45","2010-01-03 11:00","534","A","","","","","Installed washing machine","0","1","1","Indeed","",""],[
    "2010-03-20 15:00","2010-03-20 16:00","571","F","","","","","Installed oven","0","5","1","Indeed","",""],[
    etc,etc,etc...]];
```

When I append database1.js to the head on the container the memory used for IE in windows jumps from 7,7MB to 21,9MB. This is fine, I can now loop though the array called database1 (first row and column is at database1[0][0]).

The problem is that I need to re-append the database file from time to time and in doing so the memory usage increases (I thought the database array would be overwritten).

So the first re-append pushes memory usage in IE up to 30,4MB but then continues to increase on each re-append: 30,4MB > 33,9MB > 39,5MB > 42,1MB etc.

To prevent this from happening I now clear each item in the array before I re-append the database1 file.

```
for ( var i=0, il=database1.length; i<il; i++ ){
delete database1[i];
}
//append database1.js to head code here
```

*This does help*. The memory usage doesn't decrease to the initial 7,7MB but does however decrease from 21,9MB to 14,1MB. The next re-append increases the memory to 25,9MB (clearing with the loop: 18,8MB). The next re-append increases the memory to 29,3MB (clearing with the loop: 24,5MB).

**I'm glad the memory usage is not climbing as fast but perhaps this can be optimized further?** Unfortunately reloading the HTML page is not an option.

Comment: (your stackoverflow account should be fixed now)

Answer (score 6):

Memory management in JavaScript is aided by the garbage collector, a language feature that periodically deallocates memory no longer needed.

The `delete` operator essentially denotes an area of memory as being no longer needed. The memory will be deallocated when the garbage collector next runs.

Garbage collection is not predictable - `delete $var` or `$var = null` will allow the garbage collector to deallocate memory *eventually*. This may not be instant. This is why memory usage is not climbing as fast as you'd expect, and this is why `delete $var` is not reducing memory usage as fast as you'd expect.

IE does present a means for forcing the garbage collector to run:

```
if (typeof(CollectGarbage) == "function") {
    CollectGarbage();
}
```

Your script may slow down whilst this is happening, particularly if there is a large volume of memory to deallocate.

It's best to avoid forcing garbage collection - let the garbage collector run at the point it determines is most appropriate. `CollectGarbage()` is also undocumented - the behaviour may change or the function may be removed at any time.

In short:

- your use of `delete database1[i]` is the best you can do
- this will deallocate memory *eventually*
- memory usage will return to the expected level *eventually*
- you can force garbage collection in IE, but this process will eventually happen on its own

Comment: Two remarks: 1. As `typeof` is an operator, you don't have to put braces around the operand. 2. Please remember you can't `delete` [global variables](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/#property_attributes): “When declared variables and functions become properties of a Variable object — either Activation object (for Function code), or Global object (for Global code), these properties are **created with DontDelete attribute**.” But I suppose the OP is not working with global variables in this case (as memory is actually freed).

Comment: From an answer by @Ben: "Cheers Jon for that great explanation."

Comment: I am working with global variables, and using delete does free memory in my case. But perhaps delete doesn't actually delete but instead clears the item? I replaced [code]delete database1[i][/code] with [code]database1[i] = ""[/code] and this gave the same result.

Comment: Googled some more and it seems you can delete global variables in IE (perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete) read after title "IE bugs". I think, the article is a bit over my head, this means if I write "var global=1;delete global" it fails but if I define my global variables like this "global=1;delete global" then delete works (in IE). However using delete globalvar does not free memory :(